# Defining new methods for REST services - is this valid HTTP?

Tags: http, standards

According to the [HTTP protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), the list of methods can be expanded:

> ### 9 Method Definitions
>
> The set of common methods for HTTP/1.1 is defined below. Although this set can be expanded, additional methods cannot be assumed to share the same semantics for separately extended clients and servers.

Does that mean that if I write the client and server and define a new method, this is a valid HTTP 1.1 request?

```
FROB /some/url HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

Clearly "old" http clients wouldn't support this new method and it would only be an extension for the "new" client I'm writing, but my question is about the semantics of the standard and not actual implementation.

Comment: Have you taken into account various firewalls, NATs and high-level routers? They might not be very happy with `FROB` method (i.e. drop such connections.)

Comment: Can you give an example of how this might be useful and necessary versus using custom headers?

Comment: @AJ: Necessary? No. But with 'standard' HTTP, if the thing I'm doing isn't logically a `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, or `DELETE`, I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: @Tomasz: Which is one reason it's important to me to stay within the HTTP specification; then it would be the firewall's fault and not mine :)

Comment: One of the principles of REST is the "uniform interface". In principle, it's not contradictory with having your own methods, provided the representations you initially retrieve (typically via `GET`) are able to tell the client which method to use (e.g. that's what an HTML form with method `POST` does). Assuming that clients will be able to make a request with your custom method is often going to cause problems. It's usually preferable to stick with the existing method and use richer message entities (or even headers).

Comment: @Bruno: I'm talking about writing my own client and server, I'm assuming nothing about existing clients. I'm just interested in the validity of the request here.

Comment: @configurator, regarding intermediate layers, as far as I'm aware, HTTP proxy servers have no obligation to accept unknown (or even known) methods. For some, blocking certain requests is considered a feature. On the basis that "additional methods cannot be assumed to share the same semantics for separately extended clients and servers", it wouldn't necessarily be the proxy's "fault" if it doesn't want to relay your custom method.

Comment: @configurator, although what you're trying to do may not be wrong with the exact words of the specification, it will certainly cause some trouble. You'd get more help here if you gave an example where the existing methods are not suitable for what you want.

Comment: It is OK to extend methods. The spec clearly says so in Section 5.1.1. For this reason is WEBDAV an HTTP extension.